# Running multiple Appium sessions in a single test

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, appium

I am automating some tests on real devices using Appium and Cucumber and at the moment I am trying to run 2 Appium sessions a single test, something like:

- Create an instance of the Driver
- Do some tasks
- Quit the driver
- Create a new instance of the Driver with different capabilities
- Do some tasks
- Quit the driver

I am wondering what would be the correct way to implement this in **Ruby**.

Anyone with experience have any tips/advice or some code examples?
Or simply redirect me to some good documentation or code.

Comment: Why you need multiple session in single test ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want them to run at the same time you will need to create X "node appium" executions with different ports...

**Example:**

```
node appium -p 4723 -bp 4724 -U "Device1_identifier"
node appium -p 4725 -bp 4726 -U "Device2_identifier"
```

And after that you will have to create two drivers

**Java code**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities1.setCapability(...);
driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities1);

DesiredCapabilities capabilities2 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities2.setCapability(...);
driver2= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4725/wd/hub"), capabilities2);
```

2. You could create just one appium server with this argument to override sessions:

**Example:**

```
node appium --session-override
```

And then create a second driver with another capabilities after the you finished with first one...

**Java code**

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities1 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities1.setCapability("udid", "Device1_identifier"); //Not necessary if execution is at the same device
capabilities1.setCapability(...);
driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities1);
//DO THINGS WITH DRIVER HERE  
driver.findElement...
driver.something...
////////////////////////////  

DesiredCapabilities capabilities2 = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities2.setCapability("udid", "Device2_identifier"); //Not necessary if execution is at the same device
capabilities2.setCapability(...);
driver= new AndroidDriver<WebElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities2); //This will override your first Appium driver
```

Comment: sorry for such a late reply, been so busy lately :( but yes, it worked! thank you :)  @barbudito